# No swap space detected while installing WLS 12c on AIX 7.1 (Installation Crashes)

Tags: installation, weblogic, swap, aix

I'm trying to install oracle weblogic server 12c on an AIX server. The installer detects that there is no swap space on the system, but that is not true; the system has 16 GB of swap memory. You can see that from the screenshots.

Launching the Weblogic installer.

[image: weblogic installer]

Checking System swap space.

[image: swap space]

The system doesn't short on ram also.

[image: ram]

Even if I tell the installer to continue and ignore the swap space, it hangs and doesn't continue, and this is the last part of the log file of the installer.

[image: log file]

Can any body explain or help me with this problem ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never installed on AIX but you can try two things. First, run the installer with the `-ignoreSysPrereqs` option to skip over any memory checks. Second, run the installer "silently" to get more information out. Use the `-silent` option on the command line when you start the installer. You can also try these parameters:

Try

```
-debug
-logLevel finest
-printdiskusage
-printmemory
```

See the Oracle docs on [silent mode here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/silent.htm)

Comment: Great. I confirm, that just `-ignoreSysPrereqs` works, you do not have to go for the silent mode.